# How to display this pyramid of numbers?

Tags: c++

I have this task:
A user inputs a number N and you have to output this pyramid:

```
    0
   101
  21012
 .......
N.21012.N
For N=5 it will be :
     0
    101
   21012
  3210123
 432101234
54321012345
```

I managed to only get it working for N<10 with this code:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++)
        cout << " ";
    int dir = -1;
    for (int k = i; k <= i; k += dir) {
        cout << k;
        if (k == 0)
            dir = 1;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

For N=10 it will look like this :

```
           0
          101
         21012
        3210123
       432101234
      54321012345
     6543210123456
    765432101234567
   87654321012345678
  9876543210123456789
10987654321012345678910
```

Comment: what output do you get for `N>=10` and how should it look instead?

Comment: The zero should all be on the center

Comment: Yes but what should happen if number in pyramid has two digits? Provide example of row for `N = 11` and `N = 12`.

Comment: I guess, the `cout<<" ";` work only for single digits, it must be doubled for two digits, tripled for three digits, etc... I suppose this is the issue the OP encounters.

Comment: I added an example for N=10

Comment: so just calculate extra padding.

Comment: you need to adjust this part `for(int j=0;j<n-i;j++) cout<<" ";`. Instead of adding `n-i` spaces in the front you need to add more. I suppose not much can be added without spoiling the exercise completely

Comment: BTW when adding code its best to add a small compliable example that reproduces the result you get so users can test and reproduce your results: [mcve] Currently you have a small example but it's not a full program. Also notice how I fixed your code format.

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution but rather a good one, since I have an idea how to solve it but it seems just too dumb to do it this way: Start with a char array filled with spaces and start replacing with numbers from the center and display the array on each iteration. And thank you for the suggestions on the formatting. Will format next time I post a question.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to print more spaces. Is the problem one of how to format the integers being sent to `cout`?

Answer (score 2):

After the answers I settled on this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n, spaces;
  string number;
  cin >> n;
  if (n < 10)
    spaces = n;
  else
  {
    spaces = 9;
    int pwr = 0, k = n;
    while (k > 9)
    {
      pwr++;
      k /= 10;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < pwr; i++)
    {
      spaces += pow(10, i) * 9 * (i + 1);
    }
    spaces += (n - pow(10, pwr) + 1) * (pwr + 1);
  }
  // cout << spaces << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
  {
    for (int j = i; j > -1; j--)
      number += to_string(j);
    int len = number.length() - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < spaces - len; j++)
      cout << " ";
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
      number += to_string(j);
    cout << number << endl;
    number.clear();
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
int padding(int n) {
    constexpr auto singleDigitNumbersCount = 9;
    constexpr auto doubleDigitNumbersCount = 90; // from 10 to 99
    if (n < 10) return n;
    if (n < 100) return 2*n - singleDigitNumbersCount;
    return 3*n - doubleDigitNumbersCount - 2*singleDigitNumbersCount;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        std::cout << std::string(padding(n) - padding(i), ' ');
        for (int k = i; k >= 0; k--) {
            cout << k;
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
            cout << k;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EEaeWEvf4

Comment: This only works for N < 1000

Comment: Feel free to update this to any limit. Basic idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I made this a bit ago [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/n1TooYj8j)
Not sure if that'd help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_SPACE 50


int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    string output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int k = i; k >= 0; k--) {
            output += to_string(k);
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
            output += to_string(k);
        }

        for (uint8_t i = 0, max = MAX_SPACE - output.length() / 2.00; i < max; i++) // Print max spaces minus the integer length divided by 2
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << output << endl; // Print number
        output = "";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The padding is not a constant.It depends on the value of N